# `Trainer.fit` stopped: `max_steps=1` reached

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

My Pytorch model training stops after some minutes and it says that  `max_steps=1` reached. Even though I have configured this parameter to `100`. Here is how it looks in my terminal:

```
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:54: LightningDeprecationWarning: pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6 and will be removed in v1.8. Use the equivalent function from the pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero module instead.
  "pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6"
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:58: LightningDeprecationWarning: The `pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.rank_zero_experiment` is deprecated in v1.7 and will be removed in v1.9. Please use `pytorch_lightning.loggers.logger.rank_zero_experiment` instead.
  return new_rank_zero_deprecation(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:54: LightningDeprecationWarning: pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6 and will be removed in v1.8. Use the equivalent function from the pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero module instead.
  "pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6"
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:58: LightningDeprecationWarning: The `pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.rank_zero_experiment` is deprecated in v1.7 and will be removed in v1.9. Please use `pytorch_lightning.loggers.logger.rank_zero_experiment` instead.
  return new_rank_zero_deprecation(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:54: LightningDeprecationWarning: pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6 and will be removed in v1.8. Use the equivalent function from the pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero module instead.
  "pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6"
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:58: LightningDeprecationWarning: The `pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.rank_zero_experiment` is deprecated in v1.7 and will be removed in v1.9. Please use `pytorch_lightning.loggers.logger.rank_zero_experiment` instead.
  return new_rank_zero_deprecation(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:54: LightningDeprecationWarning: pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6 and will be removed in v1.8. Use the equivalent function from the pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero module instead.
  "pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6"
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:58: LightningDeprecationWarning: The `pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.rank_zero_experiment` is deprecated in v1.7 and will be removed in v1.9. Please use `pytorch_lightning.loggers.logger.rank_zero_experiment` instead.
  return new_rank_zero_deprecation(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:54: LightningDeprecationWarning: pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6 and will be removed in v1.8. Use the equivalent function from the pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero module instead.
  "pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6"
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:58: LightningDeprecationWarning: The `pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.rank_zero_experiment` is deprecated in v1.7 and will be removed in v1.9. Please use `pytorch_lightning.loggers.logger.rank_zero_experiment` instead.
  return new_rank_zero_deprecation(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:54: LightningDeprecationWarning: pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6 and will be removed in v1.8. Use the equivalent function from the pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero module instead.
  "pytorch_lightning.utilities.warnings.rank_zero_deprecation has been deprecated in v1.6"
C:\Users\r.charij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\warnings.py:58: LightningDeprecationWarning: The `pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.rank_zero_experiment` is deprecated in v1.7 and will be removed in v1.9. Please use `pytorch_lightning.loggers.logger.rank_zero_experiment` instead.
  return new_rank_zero_deprecation(*args, **kwargs)
Epoch 0: 100%|█████████| 2/2 [01:02<00:00, 31.11s/it, loss=0.123, v_num=, train/loss_step=0.123, train/angle_error_step=10.80, train/lr=0.100, val/loss=3.300, val/angle_error=88.00, train/loss_epoch=0.123, train/angle_error_epoch=10.80]`Trainer.fit` stopped: `max_steps=1` reached.
Epoch 0: 100%|█████████| 2/2 [01:02<00:00, 31.11s/it, loss=0.123, v_num=, train/loss_step=0.123, train/angle_error_step=10.80, train/lr=0.100, val/loss=3.300, val/angle_error=88.00, train/loss_epoch=0.123, train/angle_error_epoch=10.80]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using `max_steps`?

Comment: You should add the tag [pytorch-lightning] in your question if you are talking about `Trainer.fit` method of this module

Comment: @Ivan, yes and I forced it to 100 in my config file

Comment: Could this be related to the fact that I don't have GPU on my machine?, eventhough I simulated it by setting strategy=ddp and num_processes=2

Comment: Can you hardcode Trainer(max_steps=100, ...) please to make sure it's not an issue with your config loading logic, and then submit a ticket on Lightning GitHub so that we can reproduce it. Thanks
https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues

Comment: @awaelchli, thanks for your help, Actually I found the solution, even though I hard coded 'max-steps=100' it  keeps stopping and saying 'max_steps=1' reached, this is due to a parameter called 'fast_dev_run' that was set to true in my config and that had some side effects as setting max_steps to 1 for debug reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause.This was due to a parameter called 'fast_dev_run' that was set to true in my config and that had some side effects as setting max_steps to 1 for debug reasons